# Remove training data from spacy model

Tags: python, spacy, text-classification

I have trained a spacy textcat model but then I realized that there were some incorrect training data: data from one category happened to be labeled with another category. My question is: is it possible to remove these training examples from the model without retraining it? Something like `nlp.update()` but in reverse? Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to revert specific cases? As far as I know, that's not currently possible in spaCy.

I would suggest to either retrain from scratch with the corrected annotations, or continue training with the updated annotations. If you continue training, make sure that you keep feeding a representative set to your model, so that it doesn't "forget" cases it was already predicting correctly before.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! Just one more question: what do you mean under `representative set`? I met this term earlier but didn't get the meaning of it

Comment: Welcome! What I mean by that is you need to make sure the model keeps learning instances of the different labels. Image you start training it with PEOPLE and ORG, but after 2000 cases, you only continue training with PEOPLE examples, than after some time it will "forget" how to do ORG. This is referred to as the problem of catastrophic forgetting, see also https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting